# insert ole object using dxl script automatically

Tags: ibm-doors

I am new to dxl and would be very happy to know how to import a picture file For Example. JPG files(Many number of Picture round about 60 JPG files) using DXL script one after another automatically in DOORS Database.

I have tried following steps manually.

created a column with Attribute as : Object Text
double click on the row and file-->import-->OLE Object and the picture file location i have selected and it was fine, now I have more than 100 JPG files to import in DOORS Database.

It would be interesting to know how to make it automatically do it with DXL Script.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Best Regards,
San

Answer (score 0):

In the DXL Reference Manual, there is a section "OLE Objects > Picture object support" which lists all the DXL functions for handling pictures, plus some example code. Following is one of their example snippets:

```
Object currentObject = current 
bool Result = false 
string BitmapFileName = "c:\\test.bmp" 
if (currentObject == null) {
  //No objects currently exist in the module 
  Result = insertPictureFileBelow(BitmapFileName,
            formatBMP,null)
} else {
  Result = insertPictureFileBelow(BitmapFileName,
            formatBMP,currentObject)
} 
if(Result) {
    print "Successful picture insertion\n"
}
```